# how to add left menu my angular bootstrap 4 project?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, submenu

I need to add the left menu using a wapper or something npm. I need to animation it. I need to simple native code to do this.anybody please suggest the best way to do it. (angular 8, bootstrap4)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, before submitting a question, be sure to read [ask] to get the best practices of the site. Consider providing a [mcve] of your issue, so that we can see what you have tried, and tell you what's wrong (if any). Your answer is of poor quality and can be flagged as such : consider following [ask] to improve it, and remember that we're here to help you find bugs, not to do your job !

Answer (score 1):

I' didn't fully understand waht your final goal but I think this could help.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started